# How to obtain the ghost blade

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have seen people online using the ghost blade in Skyrim, but I do not know how to obtain it. Any suggestions or tips on how to get this sword?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Ghostblade](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ghostblade) is a reward for completing the quest [Ansilvund](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ansilvund_(quest)). Travel to the location named [Ansilvund](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Ansilvund) to start the quest. Here is a [map](http://srmap.uesp.net/?centeron=Ansilvund) centered on that location. It’s north of Riften, past Shor’s Stone, at the foot of the mountains on the eastern border of Skyrim.

Comment: @NightmareGamer You’re welcome. See if you can find some ectoplasm somewhere, so that you can improve the sword at a grindstone. By the way, this sort of thing is usually listed on [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Main_Page), so you might want to check there first for this sort of question.

Comment: @NightmareGamer UESP is a godsend.